# Vaadin grid lazy loading while scrolling up pages are loaded again with call to DB. How to stop this behaviour?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

In Vaadin grid lazy loading while scrolling up pages are loaded again with call to DB. How to stop this behaviour?I do not want repetitive calls to backend.

```
grid.setItems(query -> getData(id, query.getPage(), query.getPageSize()).stream());
```

Comment: What other behavior would you expect from lazy loading? If you want to avoid repeated calls by caching in memory, use eager loading rather than lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```java
Grid<YourData> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(getAllItems());
```

where `getAllItems()` returns a stream of all the items in your database.

If you don't want to load all of the items in one go, but still want to avoid fetching the same data items again, you'll need to implement your own caching; you can do this in your `getData` method.